# Log exception in a file using play

Tags: exception, logging, playframework

I want to log the exceptions in a log file using play 1.
Can anyone tell me how to configure it?
If it is a duplicate question, point it.

TIA

Comment: Please take a look inside the `logs` directory of your application. You should find what you need there. Or do you want a file containing *only* the exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use create a custom `log4j.properties` in the `conf/` directory:

Please see [logging for production](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/production#logging) for details.

Comment: yes I created them. but where can I find that logs/system.out.

Comment: you need to go to application directory and it is there. assume that your main folder is application and you have app, public, conf etc. there. then you could find application.log in that folder as you re-define output file of logs.

Comment: Nope i couldn't find anything. The app is running fine. But no logs.

Comment: First of all are you running in live/prod mode? If yes have you restarted aplication after changes?

Comment: Yes i have. 
I'm getting this warning : WARN No appenders could be found for logger (play).

Comment: could you send log4j.properties file? and do you have any configuration in application.conf file?

Comment: In log4j.properties file i just copy pasted the contents in the link you gave. And i uncommented these

           application.log=INFO
           application.log.path=/log4j.properties
           application.log.system.out=off

Comment: Sorry I should already asked this :) which version are you using? play 1.2.x or 2.x?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21004/discussion-between-huzeyfe-and-gugan)

Comment: You got me. I made a mistake. I failed to do this. "play.Logger.error("ERROR:", e);". I did it in usual log4j error writer method. Thanks a lot.